# How to gracefully terminate ffmpeg process alongside with ffprobe process?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, ffprobe, ffmpeg-python

I was able to terminate ffmpeg process gracefully when it's the only ongoing process. Now I also have ffprobe process alongside with ffmpeg process that tracks the progress of the ffmpeg process. It throws the following exception when I try to cancel the process. I tried to put the statements inside try & except blocks but I don't think it's a good solution. What's the proper way to achieve this job?

P.S. The code might be a bit confusing, but I tried to create a small executable form out of my actual code, sorry about that.

```
import subprocess as sp
import shlex
import json
import time
import threading

def start_ffmpeg_thread(audio_part, video_part, path):

    global ffmpeg_process
    if (ffmpeg_process is None) or ffmpeg_process.poll():
        data = sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 -of json "{video_part}"'), stdout=sp.PIPE).stdout
        dict = json.loads(data)
        tot_n_frames = float(dict['streams'][0]['nb_read_packets'])

        ffmpeg_process = sp.Popen(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{video_part}" -i "{audio_part}" -progress pipe:1 "{path}"'), stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)

        q = [0]

        ffmpeg_progress_reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=ffmpeg_progress_reader, args=(ffmpeg_process, q))
        ffmpeg_progress_reader_thread.start()

        while True:
            if ffmpeg_process.poll() is not None:
                break

            n_frame = q[0]
            progress_percent = (n_frame/tot_n_frames)*100
            print(f"Progress: [%] {progress_percent}", end="\r")
        ffmpeg_progress_reader_thread.join()

def ffmpeg_progress_reader(procs, q):

    while True:
        if procs.poll() is not None:
            break

        progress_text = procs.stdout.readline()
        progress_text = progress_text.decode("utf-8")
        if progress_text.startswith("frame="):
            frame = int(progress_text.partition('=')[-1])
            q[0] = frame

def cancel_ffmpeg():

    time.sleep(10)
    global ffmpeg_process
    if (ffmpeg_process is not None) and (ffmpeg_process.poll() is None):
            ffmpeg_process.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))
            ffmpeg_process.communicate()
            ffmpeg_process.wait()
            ffmpeg_process = None


ffmpeg_process = None

threading.Thread(target=cancel_ffmpeg).start()
start_ffmpeg_thread(<<AUDIO_FILE_FULL_PATH>>, <<VIDEO_FILE_FULL_PATH>>, <<OUTPUT_FULL_PATH>>)
```

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (ffmpeg_progress_reader):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()9.354796147248976
  File "D:\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "d:\Python Projects\main.py", line 82, in ffmpeg_progress_reader
    progress_text = procs.stdout.readline()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: PyMemoryView_FromBuffer(): info->buf must not be NULL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python Projects\main.py", line 101, in <module>
    start_ffmpeg_thread("aud.mp3", "vid.mp4", "output.mp4")
  File "d:\Python Projects\main.py", line 69, in start_ffmpeg_thread
    if ffmpeg_process.poll() is not None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to your immediate problem, but `shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{video_part}" -i "{audio_part}" -progress pipe:1 "{path}"')` is buggy. Don't use `shlex.split()` here; instead, generate a list explicitly (`['ffmpeg', '-y', '-loglevel', 'error', '-i', video_part, '-i', audio_part, '-progress', 'pipe:1', path]`) -- that way filenames with quote characters, literal backslashes, etc don't mess you up.

Comment: (And because ffmpeg arguments can be used to write to arbitrary files, "mess you up" in this case could mean someone could build a malicious filename that could cause ffmpeg to overwrite any file of their choice; think about `/uploads/vid.mp4" -o /etc/passwd"` -- yes, that's a legal filename, called `passwd`, in the legal directory name `/uploads/vid.mp4" -o /etc`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because FFmpeg is closed during `progress_text = procs.stdout.readline()`.

Since `readline()` is "blocking" command, there is no option to avoid the exception.
Using try & except is a valid solution in this case.

---

In case we want to avoid the exception, we have to avoid closing FFmpeg while `readline()` is waiting for data.
The "price" is that closing is not going to respond immediately, but waits until `readline()` returns.

For closing gracefully, we may use `threading.Event()` object.

- Set the event before starting the threads: `event.set()`.
- `ffmpeg_progress_reader` thread checks `if not event.is_set()` every iteration, and breaks the loop if event is "cleared".
- The last command before of `ffmpeg_progress_reader` thread is `event.set()`.
- When canceling:

  - Clear the event: `event.clear()`.
  - Wait for the event to be set: `event.wait()`.
    `event.wait()` is waiting for `ffmpeg_progress_reader` thread to finish (remember - the last command is `event.set()`).
    When `event.wait()` returns we can close FFmpeg subprocess.

---

Code sample:

```
import subprocess as sp
import shlex
import json
import time
import threading

def start_ffmpeg_thread(audio_part, video_part, path):

    global ffmpeg_process
    if (ffmpeg_process is None) or ffmpeg_process.poll():
        data = sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 -of json "{video_part}"'), stdout=sp.PIPE).stdout
        dict = json.loads(data)
        tot_n_frames = float(dict['streams'][0]['nb_read_packets'])

        ffmpeg_process = sp.Popen(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i "{video_part}" -i "{audio_part}" -progress pipe:1 "{path}"'), stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=sp.PIPE)

        q = [0]

        ffmpeg_progress_reader_thread = threading.Thread(target=ffmpeg_progress_reader, args=(ffmpeg_process, q))
        ffmpeg_progress_reader_thread.start()

        while True:
            if (ffmpeg_process is None) or (ffmpeg_process.poll() is not None):
                break

            n_frame = q[0]
            progress_percent = (n_frame/tot_n_frames)*100
            print(f"Progress: [%] {progress_percent}", end="\r")
        ffmpeg_progress_reader_thread.join()


def ffmpeg_progress_reader(procs, q):
    while True:
        if procs.poll() is not None:
            break

        progress_text = procs.stdout.readline()
        progress_text = progress_text.decode("utf-8")
        if progress_text.startswith("frame="):
            frame = int(progress_text.partition('=')[-1])
            q[0] = frame

        if not event.is_set():
            break  # Break the loop when event is clear

    event.set()  # Marks that the thread is finished.


def cancel_ffmpeg():
    time.sleep(10)

    # Clear event - causes ffmpeg_progress_reader loop to break
    event.clear()

    # Wait for ffmpeg_progress_reader thread to end (the last command of ffmpeg_progress_reader is event.set()).
    event.wait(3)  # Wait with timeout of 3 seconds (just in case...).

    # Close FFmpeg only after ffmpeg_progress_reader is ended
    global ffmpeg_process
    if (ffmpeg_process is not None) and (ffmpeg_process.poll() is None):
            ffmpeg_process.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))
            ffmpeg_process.communicate()
            ffmpeg_process.wait()
            ffmpeg_process = None


event = threading.Event()
event.set()  # Initialize event to "set" state.
ffmpeg_process = None

threading.Thread(target=cancel_ffmpeg).start()
start_ffmpeg_thread('BigBuckBunny.mp4', 'BigBuckBunny.mp4', 'tmp0.mp4')
```